# Auto refresh Table when new row added inside DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table that is connected to my DB.
I have 4 columns : Date, Time, Windspeed and Wind direction
Since my table gets a new row on average every 10 second or so I wondered if it was possible to dynamically refresh it without refreshing the whole page using AJAX.

I looked examples and tried to adjust it to my case but it just doesn't seems to work

My table looks like this

```
<table id="table" align="center" border="1px" style="width:600px; line-height:30px">
        <tr> 
                <th colspan="4"><h2> Résultat : <?php echo htmlentities($nom) ?> </h2> </th>
        </tr>
        <t>
                <th> Date </th>
                <th> Heure </th>
                <th> Vélocité (km/h) </th>
                <th> Direction du vent </th>
        </t>
    <?php
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    ?>      
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['Date'] ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['Heure'] ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['Velocite'] ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['Direction_vent'] ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

I tried this kind of refresh :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

function RefreshTable() {
   $( "#table" ).load( "valeurs.php #table" );
}

$("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Are any errors shown in the console of the browser?

Comment: No errors on the browser, when I click on the refresh button it just doesn't do anything